# If (name of array) from input value IndexOf specific value not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have html form where user enter a date.

I need script what recognize if entered date is equal to some date from array ("takeOverArray["tz27092015", "tz21102015", "tz26092015"]") (that's working) but..

Every array value (["tz27092015", "tz21102015", "tz26092015"]) is array too (datetimes).

So full array is: takeOverArray["tz27092015["mor","lun"]", "tz21102015["lun"]", "tz26092015["eve"]"]

Now, I need when entered date from form is equal to (for example:) "tz27092015" next script will find if array "tz27092015" has specific words: "mor", "lun" or "eve".  (that's not working :( and that's my problem )

My Code:

```
function checkTimeFunction() {
 var iddate= document.getElementById("takeover_date").value; //takeover_date(input from html form)
 var checkTime = "tz" + iddate.split('.').join('');

 if(takeOverArray.indexOf(checkTime, 0) !== -1) //That's working  {
    console.log("date found");

    if (checkTime.indexOf("mor", 0) !== -1) //That's NOT working {

        console.log("morning disabled");

    };
 }
})
```

So my question is, why

```
if (checkTime.indexOf("mor", 0) == 0)
```

not working like previous "indexOf" above this. And how I can figure this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `iddate.split('.').join('')` is more efficient as `iddate.replace(/\./g,'')`. Also, *indexOf* starts at 0 by default so no need for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So *takeOverArray* is an array with strings for values:

```
var takeOverArray = ["tz27092015['mor','lun']",
                     "tz21102015['lun']",
                     "tz26092015['eve']"];
```

So if the user selects, say, 27 September, 2015 then the value of *iddate* will be:

```
var iddate = '27.09.2015';
```

Convert that a the format compatible with the values in *takeOverArray* using *replace*:

```
var checkTime = 'tz' + iddate.replace(/\./g,'');
```

Now you can't use *indexOf* because it uses strict equality with array values, whereas you want to match *checkTime* with only part of the value. For that you can use [*Array.prototype.findIndex*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.findindex). That is an ECMAScript 2015 feature, but you can find a [*polyfill on MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill).

So first you want to find the index of the matching element:

```
var index = takeOverArray.findIndex(function(v) {
  return checkTime.indexOf(v) != -1;
})
```

So now if a suitable value was found, *index* will be the index of that value, or -1 if none was found. So now:

```
if (index != -1) {
  console.log("date found");

  // Test if the value at that index contains 'mor'
  if (takeOverArray[index].indexOf('mor') != -1) {
    console.log("morning disabled");
  }
} else {
  console.log("date not found");
}
```

And you're done. Here it is as runable code (requires support for *findIndex*):

```js
// Array.prototype.findIndex polyfill from MDN
if (!Array.prototype.findIndex) {
  Array.prototype.findIndex = function(predicate) {
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.findIndex called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
}



    var takeOverArray = ["tz27092015['mor','lun']",
                         "tz21102015['lun']",
                         "tz26092015['eve']"];

    var iddate = '27.09.2015';
    var checkTime = 'tz' + iddate.replace(/\./g,'');
    var index = takeOverArray.findIndex(function(v) {
      return v.indexOf(checkTime) != -1;
    })
    
    if (index != -1) {
      document.write("date found");

      // Test if the value at that index contains 'mor'
      if (takeOverArray[index].indexOf('mor') != -1) {
        document.write("morning disabled");
      }
    } else {
      document.write(checkTime + " not found");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks RobG. Unfortunately your solution don't working too :( It's like  checkTime[idx]  just not transcribed to "tz27... "  because, when i write to console "tz27092015.indexOf('mor') == 0"  return:  true.

Comment: Input:  <input type="text" onchange="checkTimeFunction();" name="takeover_date" id="takeover_date" required readonly="readonly"/>

Comment: It makes no sense to have a change listener on a text input that is readonly. It can't change, so the listener will never be called.

Comment: I have datepicker (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ) in input  and i don't want let user writing to input something else, user just gonna pick a date.  Var iddate (document.getElementById("takeover_date").value;) works perfectly, so "readonly" is ok. .. And i just tried to remove it and it works same like version with readonly.

Comment: Yes, i wrote it bad.. It's like your second code: var takeOverArray = ["tz27092015['mor','lun']",
                     "tz21102015['lun']",
                     "tz26092015['eve']"];